# SVG animation! Line expend horizontally

Tags: javascript, animation, button, svg, hamburger-menu

I am trying to make a **burger button** with **SVG image**.
On **hover**, I want each **line** of the SVG to **expend horizontally**.
How can I do this? Seems not possible with CSS.

I have been looking around in google without success on finding the answer to my question, hopefully one of you will give me hint and help!

Thanks!

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="203px" height="136px" viewBox="0 0 203 136" style="enable-background:new 0 0 203 136;" xml:space="preserve">
<line style="display:none;fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:4;stroke-miterlimit:10;" x1="11.748" y1="14.753" x2="110.604" y2="14.753"/>
<line style="display:none;fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:17;stroke-miterlimit:10;" x1="11.748" y1="68" x2="193.1" y2="68"/>
<line style="display:none;fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:17;stroke-miterlimit:10;" x1="11.748" y1="122.545" x2="157.102" y2="122.545"/>
<path style="fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#333333;stroke-width:5;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M110.604,19.11c0,3.805-3.084,6.89-6.89,6.89
 H18.638c-3.805,0-6.89-3.084-6.89-6.89l0,0c0-3.805,3.084-6.889,6.89-6.889h85.076C107.519,12.221,110.604,15.306,110.604,19.11
 L110.604,19.11z"/>
<path style="fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#333333;stroke-width:5;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M193.1,68c0,3.805-3.084,6.889-6.89,6.889
 H18.638c-3.805,0-6.89-3.084-6.89-6.889l0,0c0-3.805,3.084-6.89,6.89-6.89H186.21C190.015,61.11,193.1,64.195,193.1,68L193.1,68z"/>
<path style="fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#333333;stroke-width:5;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M157.102,118.546
 c0,3.805-3.084,6.889-6.89,6.889H18.638c-3.805,0-6.89-3.084-6.89-6.889l0,0c0-3.805,3.084-6.89,6.89-6.89h131.574
 C154.017,111.656,157.102,114.741,157.102,118.546L157.102,118.546z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: With CSS that would only work in Chrome/Opera. A SMIL solution would work in most browsers via FakeSmile so I'd pursue that if I was you.

Comment: I am checking it out. Thanks!